# Visual Studio 2013 Slow Switching between Tabs

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Everything was working fine with my Visual Studio (Ultimate 2013) today until I came back from lunch and I started getting CPU spikes every time I switch between tabs within Visual Studio (Ultimate 2013).  It especially appears to be happening when I switch between config files.

Using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), I was able to determine that it was continually searching in the packages folder:
[image]

For the same things over and over again:

[image]

How do I keep VS from doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Tools --> Nuget Package Manager --> Manage Nuget Packages For Solution...

It will prompt that not all packages have been downloaded.  Select that you'd like to download them.

Problem solved.